# Why does helm3 install trigger pre-delete and not in Helm2

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-jobs, helm3, kubernetes-rbac, k8s-serviceaccount

I have a project that needs to use `mutating Webhook`, based on `namespaceselector`, which needs to add specific **label** to namespace first.

I used three hooks, **hook1(pre-install, pre-delete,etc)** to create **RBAC** for **hook2(pre-install)** to add a label to namespace by **Job** and **hook3(pre-delete)** to remove the label by **Job**
Hook content is as follows:

**Hook1** to set permissions

```
# RBAC.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ns-edit
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade,pre-delete
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: ns-edit
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade,pre-delete
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["namespaces"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list","update","patch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: edit-ns
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade,pre-delete
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ns-edit
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: ns-edit
  namespace: kube-system
```

**hook2** to add label to namespace

```
# label-ns.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: label-ns
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "0"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: labeler
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.18.0
        command:
        - kubectl
        - label
        - ns
        - kube-system
        - mutating=disabled
        - --overwrite
      restartPolicy: Never
      serviceAccountName: ns-edit
```

**hook3** to delete label to namespace from hook2

```
# delete-ns-label.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: del-ns-label
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-delete
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "0"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: labeler
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.18.0
        command:
        - kubectl
        - label
        - ns
        - kube-system
        - mutating-
      restartPolicy: Never
      serviceAccountName: ns-edit
```

During chart deployment, both hook2 and hook3 jobs were triggered and **not complete** due to not found **serviceaccount**(ns-edit).

```
helm install mutating-webhook mutating-webhook-0.1.0.tgz --debug
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "ns-edit" ServiceAccount
client.go:283: [debug] serviceaccounts "ns-edit" not found
client.go:108: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "ns-edit" ClusterRole
client.go:283: [debug] clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "ns-edit" not found
client.go:108: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "edit-ns" ClusterRoleBinding
client.go:283: [debug] clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "edit-ns" not found
client.go:108: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:108: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:463: [debug] Watching for changes to Job label-ns with timeout of 5m0s
client.go:491: [debug] Add/Modify event for label-ns: ADDED
client.go:530: [debug] label-ns: Jobs active: 0, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:491: [debug] Add/Modify event for label-ns: MODIFIED
client.go:530: [debug] label-ns: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
client.go:491: [debug] Add/Modify event for label-ns: MODIFIED
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "ns-edit" ServiceAccount
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "ns-edit" ClusterRole
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "edit-ns" ClusterRoleBinding
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "label-ns" Job
client.go:108: [debug] creating 10 resource(s)
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "ns-edit" ServiceAccount
client.go:108: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "ns-edit" ClusterRole
client.go:108: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "edit-ns" ClusterRoleBinding
client.go:108: [debug] creating 1 resource(s)
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "ns-edit" ServiceAccount
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "ns-edit" ClusterRole
client.go:254: [debug] Starting delete for "edit-ns" ClusterRoleBinding
```

**However, it can be executed correctly in helm2, that is, hook1 and hook2 are triggered at `helm install` to add namespace label, and hook1 and hook3 are triggered at `helm delete --purge` to delete label added at hook2**

Why helm2 and helm3 have such huge differece on **Hook**.

May I ask how to modify to achieve the **unification** of the two? If not, how to design in **helm3**

I really appreciate any help with this.

> Notes: helm2 is v2.17.0, helm3 is v3.3.0

Comment: As per Helm's [kind ordering](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/484d43913f97292648c867b56768775a55e4bba6/pkg/releaseutil/kind_sorter.go), Jobs will always be installed after ServiceAccounts and Roles; does it work to set all the jobs to the same weight?  Or, does it work to set the ServiceAccount _etc._ to not delete itself when "complete"?

Comment: after I delete weight fo RBAC, and modify **label-ns** to `hook-weight": "1"`,   **del-ns-label** to `hook-weight": "3"`.  When `helm install` is performed, both jobs are called, causing **labels of namespace** to be `deleted immediately after creation`, and both jobs are not deleted as expected ("helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook- Succeeded)